# wp_editor not saving line breaks or bold

Tags: wordpress, styles, wp-editor

Im busy writing a store description for my multi store woocommerse site on wordpress.

Im using the wp_editor.

But I cant get it to save the styling parts. Bold, Itallic, linebreaks, nothing saves, it just saves `&nbsp` where the `<strong></strong>, <br>` should be.

Also links is saved as text

my code to call wp_editor:

```
 $content =  stripslashes(esc_textarea( $storediscrip ));
 $editor_id = 'dokan_store_discrip';

 $settings =   array('editor_height' => 100, 'quicktags' => false, 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce' => true, 'teeny'=> false, 'editor_class' => 'dokan_store_discrip', 'wpautop' => true);

            wp_editor( $content , $editor_id, $settings  );
```

my code to echo:

```
<div> <?php echo wpautop( $store_info['store_discrip']);  ?></div>
```

I've tried echo in `<a>` , `<p>` , with `stripslashes(`

I'm at a loss here, spent almost 3 days on it, with too many variants to mention, and cant seem to crack it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.